# Routing to a directory with a leading period?

Tags: url-routing, web2py, lets-encrypt

Trying to enable letsencrypt with web2py.  As part of that I may need to create a route for a url like `www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/<some long string>`

As I test this I notice that the following route works:

```
('/\.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html',
 '/some_app/static/well-known/acme-challenge/test.html'),
```

While this almost identical route doesn't:

```
('/\.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html',
 '/some_app/static/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html'),
```

The only difference between these two routes is that in the latter one, in the second element of the tuple, `.well-known` has a leading period while the former route has `well-known` without a period.

Note I did try escaping the period like `\.well-known` but it doesn't work either.

Why does the route with the leading period not work? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is a static URL, the path segment immediately after `/static/` is interpreted as the controller function and is therefore expected to be a valid Python identifier (the regular expression used to match that part of the path is `\w+`).

Note, rather than having web2py serve the letsencrypt response, you might consider configuring your web server to return the response directly (e.g., it is easy to configure Nginx to do this).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across a direct solution to the leading period issue (as mentioned by Anthony web2py expects a valid python identifier)

However, to solve the specific problem of working with Let's Encrypt I did follow Anthony's suggestion to handle it in the webserver.  I am using Apache, in my httpd.conf I added:

```
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

Alias "/.well-known/" "/var/www/html/somedirectory/.well-known/"
```

Note [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) will automatically map whatever comes after the url path.  Example with the above Alias:

`example.com/.well-known/something/hello`

will map to

`/var/www/html/somedirectory/.well-known/something/hello`